# Redux-Saga call effect always ends on catch block

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-saga

I'm using Google Translate API and translating texts before populating store with some data, but using `call()` effect to translate effects, the response always go into catch block, even when the translate request is successful

Here is my saga:

```
function* getResults({ payload = 'user' }: ActionType<typeof actions.getResultsRequest>) {
  try {
    const { data } = yield call(api, `/results/${payload === 'user' ? 'me' : 'team'}`);
    const currentLanguage = getSavedState('user.currentLanguage')
    if (currentLanguage !== "ptBR") {
      const { results: statistics, adequate_protection, ...rest } = data
      const translatedProtection: ReturnType<typeof translateText> = yield call(translateText(data.adequate_protection, currentLanguage.replace(/[^a-z]/g, '')))
      yield put(actions.getResultsSuccess({ statistics, analysis: { ...rest, adequate_protection: translatedProtection } }));
    } else {
      const { results: statistics, ...rest } = data
      yield put(actions.getResultsSuccess({ statistics, analysis: { ...rest } }));
    }
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(actions.getResultsFailure({ status: true, message: 'Ocorreu um erro' }))
  }
}
```

And this is the `translateText()`

```
export const translateText = async (
  text: string | Array<string>,
  targetLanguage: string
) => {
  try {
    const [response] = await translate.translate(text, targetLanguage)
    let result: string | Array<string> = response

    if (Array.isArray(response)) {
      result = response.map((val: string, index) =>
        val !== '' ? val : text[index]
      )
    }
    return result
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error translate api =>', `${error}`)
    return text
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`call`](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#callfn-args) takes a function and its args, but you're *calling* `translateText` and passing the resulting `Promise` into `call`.  The `error` you are getting is likely a `TypeError` saying that the argument `fn` of type `Promise` is not `callable`.

If you change:

```
yield call(
  translateText(data.adequate_protection,
  currentLanguage.replace(/[^a-z]/g, ''))
)
```

to:

```
yield call(
  translateText,
  data.adequate_protection,
  currentLanguage.replace(/[^a-z]/g, '')
)
```

then things should *just work*.